# filtering data on a non-uniform, annular domain

Tags: python, filter, signal-processing

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how I should proceed re the following.

I want to apply a **Gaussian filter** to data that live on a **3D non-uniform annular domain**.
For each 3D cell in this 3D domain, I have the (x, y, z) coordinates and the corresponding data that I want to filter. Something else to keep in mind is that the domain size is large, in the order of a few million spatial degrees of freedom, therefore I also need to worry about the efficiency of the filtering algorithm.

The standard Gaussian filter is defined for uniform data on a Euclidean domain.

The question is: how should I account for the non-uniformity of the mesh and the fact that my domain is annular when performing the filtering?

I do not want to interpolate my data onto a structured, rectangular mesh and do the filtering there because I do not want to lose any information, if possible.

The end goal is to filter the data with a low-pass filter, therefore if Gaussian filtering is too complicated for my setup, I could try something else if you have other recommendations.

Much appreciated!

Writing the code for this problem will not be difficult, I am interested in how to approach it conceptually. Needless to say, most existing implementations for Gaussian filtering are not suitable here.